# What does 'this' mean when you use 'super'?

Tags: javascript, class, this, super

```html
<script>
    
      const base = {
        name: "C",
        sayHi() {
          console.log(this.name); // A     how and why 'this' refers to the derived2 object??
        },
      };

      const derived = {
        __proto__: base,
        name: "B",
        sayHi() {
          super.sayHi();
        },
      };

      const derived2 = {
        __proto__: derived,
        name: "A",
        sayHi() {
          super.sayHi();
        },
      };

      derived2.sayHi();
</script>
```

I thought `this` in the base object refers to the derived object.

Because `super` in `derived.sayHi` means `derived.__proto__`( base object ).

I've learned that `this` in method refers to the object that calls that.

But actually `this` on the base object prints `derived2` and `console.log(this.name)` is `A`.

How does it work??

I know `super = Obejct.getPrototypeOf( [[ Homeobject ]] )`

What am I mistaken for?

Comment: Not an expert, but your `derived2` object's has only one `name` property and its value is `"A"` so guess what gets printed when you `print(derived2.name)`?

Comment: yeah. I know print(derived2.name) is 'A'. but i don't know why 'this' in base.sayHi refers to derived object.

Comment: because you call it *from* the derived object

Comment: becase super.sayHi() in derived object called base.sayHi(), i thought 'this' refers to super( = base ). 

when using inheritance of functions,  this is equal to the object that the function was originally called on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` referring to "the base class" makes little sense to begin with. When invoking a (non-static) method, all `this` can refer to is an *instance* of some object.
Imagine a parent method modifying an attribute. What instance should it modify if not the one calling that method? Clearly, `this` can only refer to the instance invoking any method, `super` or not.

As far as I know, the MDN is [not explicit about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super). Maybe they assume it's not worth mentioning?

This mechanism, however, does make the handling of `this` in an ECMAScript engine even more complicated than before :)

Assuming I got it right, this is what the ECMA standard says on the matter:

§ [13.3.7](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-super-keyword): `the` **`super`** `keyword`, in the section  `SuperProperty : super . IdentifierName` (which corresponds to your `super.A`), tells us this syntactic element will be evaluated as `MakeSuperPropertyReference` with the value of `this` found in the current "Environment Record" (that of the derived class in your example) and the specified property key (i.e. the name of the method, `A` in your case).
The section just above covers the case of seeing an object as a string-indexed array of properties (i.e. the `super["A"]` notation equivalent to `super.A`)

§ [13.3.7.3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-makesuperpropertyreference) `MakeSuperPropertyReference` tells us this call will return a `ReferenceRecord`

§ [6.2.4](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#super-reference-record) `The Reference Record Specification Type` explains that"*In [the `super`] case, the `[[ThisValue]]` field holds the this value **at the time the Reference Record was created***"

§ [13.3.6.2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-evaluatecall) `EvaluateCall` applied to the parent object method will hit case `1.b` of the pseudo-code and get back the `this` value of the original caller (i.e. your derived class instance).

So, apparently, while `[HomeObject]` is used to walk the prototype chain, the handling of `this` is defined with yet another logic.
Don't ask me why: I didn't write the spec, I'm only painstakingly trying to make sense of it :)

Answer (score -1):

The `this` variable does not cast to different classes when using inheritance of functions. `this` is equal to **the object that the function was originally called on**, as-is. (there are some exceptions for arrow functions).

```
class A {
  sayHi() { console.log(this.prototype.name); }
}
class B extends A {
  sayHi() { super.sayHi(); }
}

const obj1 = new B();
const obj2 = new A();

obj1.sayHi(); // B.sayHi calls A.sayHi with `this` being simply obj1.
// Logs "B"

obj2.sayHi(); // A.sayHi runs with `this` being obj2.
// Logs "A"
```

Comment: @juuuo I have edited the answer for clarity, does this help?

Comment: and why 'this' does not cast to differrent classes when using inheritance of functions? 
If there is anything related to it in the MDN, could you put up a link?